# 'effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController not found

Tags: ros, simulation, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros-users,
I'm using the simulator for youbot in ros-hydro (package youbot_gazebo_robot)
Launching the youbot.launch I got this problem on the controller of the arm

[ERROR] [1402654097.573003559, 0.963000000]: Could not load controller 'arm_1/arm_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.

The package effort_controllers is correctly installed

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173545/%27effort_controllers/jointtrajectorycontroller-not-found/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` does not live in the `effort_controllers` package, although I see how you might have thought it does.

You need to install the `ros-hydro-joint-trajectory-controller` package.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1